# Logcat stops logging when date is changed to the past

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I have a broadcast receiver which tracks the change of date:

```
public class MyDateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.i("intent ","date has changed");
    }
}

<receiver android:name=".MyDateChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This works fine when I change the date (in the emulator) to the future, but as soon as I change the date to something in the past, the logging completely stops.

If today is Jan 1:

> Date changed to Jan 5 - **Logged**
>
> Date changed to Dec 25 - **All logging stops**
>
> Date changed back to Jan 3 - **Still no log**
>
> Date changed to Jan 10 - **Logging resumes**
>
> Date changed to Jan 9 - **Logging stops**
>
> Date changed to Jan 20 - **Logging resumes**

And so on..

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to report this to google

Comment: This is a bug report, not really a question.

Comment: I'd say that this behavior could be expected. The cause could be that the logs are shown in order of time appeared. And if you change time backward, the logs should probably appear higher in the logcat

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't see the logs from the older dates at all anywhere.